# Vue - reload data after href download starts

Tags: javascript, ajax, vue.js

I am making a simple `window.location.href` call to start a file download. After that, I call a method to reload a table.

```
window.location.href = url;
this.getFileListing();
```

But the reload is too fast, because the href creates a database record.

Adding a 1 second timeout fixes it:

```
window.location.href = url;
setTimeout(() => {
    this.getFileListing();
}, 1000);
```

...but that's sloppy. How do I wait for the download to start (thus the database record will exist) before I call the reload?

*Note: the location of the window does not change. I am just using windows.location.href to call a local route, which starts downloading a file. Therefore, I do not believe popstate or hashchange will work.

Comment: If the `url` is of the same origin, you may want to investigate using an anchor tag with the download property. This will allow you to trigger a download without causing a reload: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a#attr-download

Answer (score 1):

instead of launch download with `window.location.href` for vue you can use axios to download a file and use `then` method on promise  to launch the needed method

```
 axios({
   url: url,
   method: 'GET',
   responseType: 'blob'
 .then(response => (this.getFileListing()))
```

If you are using jQuery you can try something equivalent with jquery get https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/

```
var instance = this;
$.get("fileToDownload", function() {
    //code when download is launch
}).done(function() {
    instance.getFileListing();
})
```

Comment: Great thought! However, I only have access to jQuery, not axios (not my decision).

Comment: it run i add a sample with jquery usign get in my reply

Answer (score 0):

My solution: to use axios and a LOT of code to grab the response, and pass it to the browser. I had to parse out the original filename. Not sure if it was worth it. I actually put the functions in a mixin so I could add it easily to other components.

```
downloadToBrowser(url, successCallback) {
  axios({
    method: 'GET',
    url: url,
    responseType: 'blob'
  })
  .then(response => {
    this.startDownload(response);
    successCallback();
  });
},
startDownload(response) {
  var filename = response.headers['content-disposition'].split('=')[1];
  const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([response.data]));
  const link = document.createElement('a');
  link.href = url;
  link.setAttribute('download', filename);
  document.body.appendChild(link);
  link.click();
},
```

Then call the method, passing in the url and callback:

```
this.downloadToBrowser(url, this.getFileListing);
```

*If you have any comments about something I could do better/differently, I welcome the feedback.